# How to apply formControl from FormArray to input element Angular?

Tags: angular

I have written a custom FormGroup as `AddLayerFormGroup` and custom control `CustomFormControl`:

**Custom Control**

```
export class CustomFormControl extends FormControl {
      public label: string;
      public name: string;
      public type: string;
    
      constructor(
        name,
        options = [],
        customOptions = <CustomFormControlOptions>{}
      ) {
        super(name, options);
    
        this.setLabel(customOptions.name);
        this.setName(customOptions.field);
        this.setType(customOptions.type);
      }
    
      setLabel(label: string) {
        this.label = label;
      }
    
      setName(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    
      setType(type: string) {
        this.type = type;
      }
    }
```

**Custom form group:**

```
export class AddLayerFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  private formArray = new FormArray([]);

  constructor(options = {}) {
    super(options);
  }

  createControls(fields: any) {
    this.addControl("items", this.formArray);
    fields
      .filter((field) => !!field.htmlInputAttr)
      .forEach((field) => {
        this.formArray.push(this.getControl(field));
      });
  }

  getControl(_fields: any): CustomFormControl {
    const { htmlInputAttr, value, field, name } = _fields;
    const { type } = htmlInputAttr;
    const control = new CustomFormControl(name, [], { name, field, type });

    if (value) {
      control.setValue(value);
    }

    if (htmlInputAttr?.required) {
      control.setValidators([Validators.required, ValidateEmpty]);
    }

    if (htmlInputAttr?.disabled) {
      control.disable();
    }

    return control;
  }

  getControls() {
    return this.controls.items["controls"];
  }
}
```

I try to use it like:

**HTML template where controls iterates**

```
<form [formGroup]="addLayerForm">
<ol-edit-field *ngFor="let control of addLayerForm.getControls()"
[formGroup]="addLayerForm"
[formControl]="control">
</ol-edit-field>
</form>
```

**The component where I pass control:**

```
<input autocomplete="off"
 [formGroupName]="formControl"
 type="text"
 pInputText
/>
```

I got the error:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name
> attribute.
> ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '1'

I have tried this:

```
<form [formGroup]="addLayerForm">
   <div formArrayName="items">
      <ol-edit-field
      *ngFor="
      let control of addLayerForm.getControls();
      let i = index
      "
      [formControl]="control"
      [formGroupName]="i"
      [formGroup]="addLayerForm"
      ></ol-edit-field>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Template of component is:**

```
 <div[formGroupName]="formGroupName">
   <input [formControlName]="formControl.name">
</div>
```

Dump of formGroup is:

[image]

Comment: The way you formatted your question is very hard to follow, split your code into respective files and add some kind of title. We cant tell if the html is related to your classes or some other ts nor whats the relation between those samples.

Comment: Done, you can check it out

Comment: I think you should not extend `FormGroup` and `FormControl` but use an object to control it. This post helped me alot learning about Formarray and how it can be used. https://netbasal.com/angular-reactive-forms-the-ultimate-guide-to-formarray-3adbe6b0b61a

Comment: This is simple version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-8xvunz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some the input variable names mixed up in your template and component. I didn't go through your actual code in the question, but used the stackblitz from your comment, to make it a workable demo.

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-bvppy2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Hope you can take the hint from it to get your actual code working :)

html:

```
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input type="checkbox" formControlName="published"> Published
      <div *ngIf="form.controls.published.value">

        <h2>Credentials</h2>
        <button (click)="addCreds()">Add</button>

        <div *ngIf="f.length > 0">
          <div *ngFor="let creds of f.controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroup]="creds">
              <ng-container>
                <input placeholder="Username" formControlName="name">
                <input placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
              </ng-container>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Below code added for demo purposes -->
    <br>
    <div *ngIf="f.length > 0">
      <div *ngFor="let creds of f.controls; let i = index">
        <p>Form {{ i + 1}} Data:</p>
        <p>username: {{ creds.controls.name.value }}</p>
        <p>password: {{ creds.controls.password.value }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      published: true,
      credentials: new FormArray([])
    });
  }

  addCreds() {
    this.f.push(this.fb.group({
      name: [null],
      password: [null]
    }));
    console.log(this.form);
  }

  get f() {
    return this.form.controls.credentials as FormArray;
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]